# Replace Spaces inside Square Brackets with Regex in Notepad++ []

Tags: sql, replace, notepad++

I have SQL views such as the below:

```
SELECT e.employeeid as [EmployeeID], e.employeedescnoid as [Employee Name],
mgr.employeedesc as [Works For], vh.[path] as Hierarchy,
vh.HierarchyLevel1 as [Hierarchy Level 1],
vh.HierarchyLevel2 as [Hierarchy Level 2],
vh.HierarchyLevel3 as [Hierarchy Level 3],
```

They get much bigger and I am having to replace spaces inside the [] brackets with an underscore. Many examples I find either dont work or also replace spaces outside the brackets - is there a regex code I can use in notepadd++ find and replace to do this.

Comment: If they are all called `Hierarchy Level nnn` then you can repace `'Hierarchy Level '` with `'Hierarchy_Level_'`.

Comment: To be more specific & correct you should replace "[Hierarchy Level " with "Hierarchy_Level_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job in multiple steps:

Find what: `(?<=\[)(\w+)` <-- note the space at the end
Replace with: `$1_`

Make sure that `Regular expression` is checked.
Click on `Replace All` as many time as necessary to replace all the spaces.

Comment: In addition to Notepad++ (which is awesome) I also use Expresso, which a completely free RegEx editor that allows you to construct RegExes in a number of ways and execute them against sample data to ensure you get what you were expecting. It makes writing a nd testing RegExes so much faster. They're nothing to do with me but it's pulled my ass out of the fire when debugging RegExes so many times that I figured they deserve some love in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it in multiple steps. Set the **Find what** to `(\[[^ \[\]]*) ([^\[\]]*\])` and the replace with to be `\1_\2`. On each step one space between the brackets will be replaced.

The regular expression is decoded as follows:

```
(             Start of first capture group
\[            A real square bracket
[^ \[\]]*     Zero or more characters that are not space or square brackets
)             End of the first capture
              One real space
(             Start of second capture group
[^\[\]]*      Zero or more characters that are not square brackets
\]            A real closing bracket
)
```

If the text within the square brackets must not contain line breaks you could change the **Find what** to `(\[[^ \[\]\r\n]*) ([^\[\]\r\n]*\])`